# Access Database theory/design

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on building a database for tracking details of a large collection (40k) of architectural drawings.  One of the details we want to track about each drawing is the floor numbers represented.  Since some drawings have multiple floors there needs to be a way to account for this.  My database theory isn't top rate so Im not sure if my solution is the logical way to go.

My solution would be to create a one to many relationship between the drawings primary key and a new Floors table with a record for every floor, using a third table of Floor Names as a lookup source for consistency.  I.E. if a drawing represented floors 1 and 2 there would be two records in my floors table related to the drawings primary ID.

I had considered a one to one relationship and boolean fields for every floor, but since some buildings have upwards of 20 floors there would be a lot of fields, and many would be NULL as very few buildings have more than 5 floors.

Is my approach here a suitable solution?  Thanks!

Comment: I would take a look at [normalization](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/) this will make the database much more reliable, and flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify you want to record floor(s)and name?  I was in construction for many years. I would make a few new tables.

```
tblProject
Project#(pk), ProjectName, ...(project details)

tblSheetDetail
SHEETID(seq), Sheet#(A1), Project#(fk), SheetTitle, 

tblTrades
TradeID, TradeName, SpecCode

tblFloor
FloorID, Floor#, 

tblTradesSheetDetail
TSDetailID,SheetID(fk), TradeID(fk),  

tblFloorSheetDetail
FSDetailID, SheetID(fk), FloorID(fk)
```

Now you can pull data almost anyway you could imagine.  We found the TradeSheet detail table most helpful. You might also consider a table to record revisions to each sheet.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for.  I already have tables for projects, and sets for grouping As-Built or 100%CD records. The TradeSheet is a good idea.  I have a field for discipline but some drawings are a combination so your solution makes a lot more sense.